# Laravel routes explanation

Tags: php, rest, laravel

I am researching RESTful api's at the moment, and I have come across this route,

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    if (Request::is('api/*')) {

        return ErrorResponse::make('API endpoint for this verb not found.', 404);
    }
    else {

        return 'Page not found.';
    }
});
```

I'm really sure what it does, can anyone enlighten me? Is it an essential route in a RESTful API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a route, it is a Laravel error handler for 404 errors. It basically checks to see if the url was /api/{any} if it was it will then return an error for the api consumer. Otherwise it was mostly likely a human and therefore just returns the text 'Page not found.'

A couple of things to note here:

1) `ErrorResponse` is not a native laravel class, you'll have to define it yourself I'm guessing in this case it returns json with a 404 status.

2) I'm guessing you are thinking this is a route as you found it in Routes.php, although you can put error handlers here it is a better idea to put them somewhere like start/global.php

3) The case where it returns 'Page not found' it isn't returning a 404 status code.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your application, if a page cannot be found (i.e. a 404) - it will call this function
2. The application checks if the missing route started with `/api/` (i.e. `/api/this-does-not-exist`.)
3. If it was an "api" route that it is missing, it returns a special error response code (probably JSON) - so that the api can read it
4. Otherwise it just returns "page not found" for all other 404 on your site